# Which metadata table in Oracle has detailed information about IDENTITY columns?

Tags: oracle

New to Oracle and using Oracle 12c here, I have a few tables with IDENTITY columns on them, how do I figure out if the IDENTITY type on the column is "ALWAYS GENERATED" or "DEFAULT"? Are there any meta data sys tables I can query that are identity specific?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The catalog view `USER_TAB_IDENTITY_COLS` (or `ALL_` or `DBA_` depending on what you need and what privileges you have) will give you the information you need.

However, if you want to distinguish between `BY DEFAULT` and `BY DEFAULT ON NULL` you will need to query the `*_TAB_COLUMNS` views.

Neither view has ALL the possible information one might want - you will need to query both views to get all the details.

```
create table s ( x number generated always             as identity);
create table t ( y number generated by default         as identity);
create table u ( z number generated by default on null as identity);

select table_name, column_name, generation_type
from   user_tab_identity_cols
where  table_name in ('S', 'T', 'U')
;

TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME  GENERATION_TYPE     
------------ ------------ ---------------  
S            X            ALWAYS 
T            Y            BY DEFAULT  
U            Z            BY DEFAULT 


select table_name, column_name, identity_column, default_on_null
from   user_tab_columns
where  table_name in ('S', 'T', 'U')
;

TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME  IDENTITY_COLUMN DEFAULT_ON_NULL
------------ ------------ --------------- ---------------
S            X            YES             NO 
T            Y            YES             NO 
U            Z            YES             YES
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, very helpful! Is there also a way to know about other IDENTITY properties like start number, end number, interval, etc. Basically, what I need to do is - see if there's a "ALWAYS" type of identity, turn it off for some time and then turn it back on. For in order to turn it back on, I think those other details would be necessary as well.

Comment: Also, maybe I am missing something but these views are empty for me, even though I do have a table with generated IDENTITY "ALWAYS" type. I should mention that table has no data though.

Comment: Ok. I could all the required information from sys.all_tab_identity_cols. It also has other information like min value, max value, start with, etc. That I was looking for. Thanks for your answer though!